# Should I reuse a handler between loggers?

Tags: python, python-logging

Should I reuse a handler between loggers? It looks like I *can*:

```py
import logging
import sys

fmt = logging.Formatter('My little handler:\t%(message)s')
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout) # for testing purposes (in reality this goes to a log file)
handler.setFormatter(fmt)

logger_1 = logging.getLogger("Numero uno")
logger_1.addHandler(handler)
logger_1.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger_2 = logging.getLogger("Numero duo")
logger_2.addHandler(handler)
logger_2.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger_1.info("Info to 1")
logger_2.info("Info to 2")
logger_1.debug("Debug to 1")
logger_2.debug("Debug to 2")

# Output is as expected:
# My little handler:      Info to 1
# My little handler:      Info to 2
# My little handler:      Debug to 2
```

But *should* I? Is there anything that could go wrong with such a setup?

In case it matters, my intended use case is as follows

- many loggers (one per module)
- two handlers per logger

  - one handler shared by all loggers: everything of level INFO or more is written to `main.log`, with a consistent formatting
  - one logger-specific handler: everything (even DEBUG statements) from module `foo` is written to `foo.log` (but formatting may be different across modules/loggers).

Answer (score 0):

Reusing a handler appears to be fine. `Logger.addHandler` just adds the handler to a list on the logger, handler is not modified. In the case of a stream handler, ultimately they'll both access the same std out even if using multiple instances of `StreamHandler`, so that's not an issue either.

Regarding the one handler shared by all loggers, either your adding the handler where you're creating the logger or your maintaining a list that needs to updated every time you make a new module (or remove one). Either way, consider having a logger in `main` and then using a child of that in each of the modules. Then you only have to add the handler in one place, the parent.

Regarding the file handler per module logger. Again, consider using that `main` logger with child loggers in each module. You would add a single `FileHandler` to the parent and then using something like LogMx to view the log.

It's usually a bad idea to be adding handlers in the library at all. Having multiple handlers sprinkled through the code base would be a nightmare to manage.